# Why can I not start mysqld_safe on Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL)?

Tags: mysql, redhat, rhel4

I downloaded mysql-5.1.44.tar.gz and installed it by issuing the following commands:

```
$ ./configure
$ make
$ make install
```

Everything installed without any error. Next, I tried to start the mysql server by issuing the following command:

```
$ mysqld_safe --user=mysql &
100310 13:25:56 mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/var/perfportal2.err'.
100310 13:25:56 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/var
100310 13:25:56 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/var/perfportal2.pid ended

$ cat /usr/local/var/myserver.err 
100310 13:25:56 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/var
/usr/local/libexec/mysqld: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist
100310 13:25:56 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
100310 13:25:56 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.host' doesn't exist
100310 13:25:56 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/var/perfportal2.pid ended
```

My guess is the installation process did not create the data directory.

Any suggestions about what I should do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you ran `make install` and already had the `mysql-server` package installed, chances are you had a pre-existing `mysql` database schema in /var/lib/mysql.  The version included with RHEL5 is 5.0.77, which could explain the mysql-upgrade error, as that script updates the schema between MySQL versions.  The error could also be very similar if you did not create the initial schema as part of your installation.

If you're going to compile from source and not specify installation locations, you need to remove the system packages of mysql first.  If you want to maintain both the system packages and the source installation, which there is sometimes argument for, you need to be careful not to stomp all over the system package.  That typically means installing your source in a location such as `/usr/local/mysql` as opposed to the default of `/usr/local`.  You can accomplish this with `./configure --prefix=/usr/local/mysql`.  There are more details here and best practices that I'm not going to elaborate further on.

While there can be good reasons to compile from source, you might reconsider yours, as it may not be necessary for you.

`rpm -qa | grep mysql` will display all packages currently installed.  Probably `mysql-server` and `mysql-client`.

Otherwise, you didn't follow the procedure from the documentation.  Even if you did, you will have to repeat it after removing the MySQL packages.

From `INSTALL-SOURCE`, which was included in the mysql-5.1.44 tarball:

```
2.3.1. Source Installation Overview

   The basic commands that you must execute to install a MySQL source
   distribution are:
shell> groupadd mysql
shell> useradd -g mysql mysql
shell> gunzip < mysql-VERSION.tar.gz | tar -xvf -
shell> cd mysql-VERSION
shell> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/mysql
shell> make
shell> make install
shell> cp support-files/my-medium.cnf /etc/my.cnf
shell> cd /usr/local/mysql
shell> chown -R mysql .
shell> chgrp -R mysql .
shell> bin/mysql_install_db --user=mysql
shell> chown -R root .
shell> chown -R mysql var
shell> bin/mysqld_safe --user=mysql &
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, Warner. I missed the mysql_install_db step.

Answer (score 0):

1. **Install software from packages!!! Say No to source code compilation. It's 2010 now, you know?**
   If there is no  package for your software then you should [build it yourself](http://www.rpm.org/wiki/Docs#UserDocumentation).
2. Error message clearly says that you should run `mysql_upgrade`
3. You also can try running `mysql_install_db` if above doesn't work out.

Comment: I disagree with your first point and I suspect I'm not the only one. Nevertheless, the exampled skill-level does seem more suitable for binary packages.

Comment: I completely disagree with your first point also.

Comment: @SaveTheRbtz: Thank you for answering. In this case, I do need to install from source. I also tried to run mysql_upgrade, but failed. The missing step was mysql_install_db.